# In-app Purchase php validation openssl verify, openssl_get_publickey

Tags: php, openssl, in-app-purchase

I have been trying to verify the inapp purchase from server side after getting the response from frontend 
**android side**. Frontend developer send me below information. I am using openssl_get_publickey() for public key (Get from the google console) and openssl_verify() function but Getting false/0 response each time. Please help me to solve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

```
        $signedData =  array(
            "orderId"           => 'GPA.3333-5628-5675-XXXX',
            "packageName"       => 'com.xxxxxxxx',
            "productId"         => 'sample_test_purchase',
            "purchaseTime"      => 1539165004552,
            "purchaseState"     => 0,
            "purchaseToken"     => $purchase_token
        );
    $signedData = json_encode($signedData); 


    $base64EncodedPublicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlrVLmLsjKbT+D96evuqmVrMq5FnTVtYOJY5AF2R/sadfasfasdfasdfasdfasdf+DQ3kCxGj+dfgdsxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXx/NZyXxxxxxxxx";


    $key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" . chunk_split($base64EncodedPublicKey, 64, "\n") . '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
    $key = openssl_get_publickey($key);
    $sign=base64_decode($input_fields->signature);
    $result   = openssl_verify($signedData,$sign,$key,OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
```

output : 0 or false
result is0error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio

Comment: do you solved this problem?